# OpenMP on iOS/Android

Tags: android, c++, ios, cross-platform, openmp

OpenMP is supported in GCC which is cross-platform... but does that mean OpenMP is supported on all target platforms? Specifically, iOS and Android**... as phones/tablets move to quad-core, not using all the cores in games will be a huge disadvantage.

** *As a non mobile-developer I don't know if you can write C++ apps for Android in the first place?*

Answer (score 3):

This is not necessarily the case. Example: http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/a547eac5446035b4?pli=1

OMP is not supported on all target GCC platforms. It's certainly not available for Gameboy Advance, e.g., even though GCC can target ARM/Thumb architectures.

On the iOS side, I'm not sure if OMP is supported or not, but Apple would probably strongly encourage the use of their Grand Central Dispatch library with focus on asynchronous task queuing (Apple really pushes that one with the ideal being that applications should never stall and show a loading icon which is quite different from just parallel loops to speed up sequential processing).

> As a non mobile-developer I don't know if you can write C++ apps for
>   Android in the first place?

Yes, C and C++ with the Android NDK are the two languages supported for building native Android applications, while iOS focuses on C, C++, and Objective-C.

Comment: Regarding Apple's own libs - I specifically need code that works on different platforms, and I imagine Apple's stuff is different enough that it would introduce too many problems. Isn't the point that GCC could make the iOS OpenMP implementation _use_ GCD?

Comment: That's true. Your basic OMP parallel for could be implemented using code blocks and GCD in theory at least with dispatch_apply. As of yet, I don't see any support for it in clang and Apple tends to be a bit of a proprietary control freak so I'm not sure how much hope we can have of seeing OMP support in the near future. When Apple creates something like GCD, they're generally going to push it in favor of more cross-platform solutions based on what I've seen of their track record.

Comment: If you're looking for portable solutions, you might fare best with something that can sit on top of C++ as is the case with thread-building blocks which doesn't require the compiler to actually acknowledge its presence to work.

Comment: ... however, there is no single C++ solution as of yet to my knowledge which works on all these platforms.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't official support for OpenMP in iOS, but with the `-Xclang -fopenmp` flag, we can enable the hidden OpenMP support in Apple's Clang.

Unfortunately Apple didn't provide the library also,
you may notice `brew install libomp` provides you a `libomp.a`, but that is compiled for macOS and you cannot link it with iOS app.

So we need to compile it ourselves for iOS:

```
wget https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-14.0.6/openmp-14.0.6.src.tar.xz
tar -xf openmp-14.0.6.src.tar.xz
cd openmp-14.0.6.src

mkdir -p build
cmake -B build \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=ios.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./build/install \
    -DIOS_PLATFORM=OS -DENABLE_BITCODE=1 -DENABLE_ARC=0 -DENABLE_VISIBILITY=0 -DIOS_ARCH="arm64;arm64e" \
    -DPERL_EXECUTABLE=$(which perl) \
    -DLIBOMP_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF -DLIBOMP_OMPT_SUPPORT=OFF -DLIBOMP_USE_HWLOC=OFF
cmake --build build -j 3
cmake --build build --target install
```

The above would create a static library `libomp.a`,

Here's my implementation on creating a `OpenMP.xcframework` which can support both iOS and iPhone Simulator: https://github.com/flyinghead/flycast/pull/805/

Comment: Apparently the version of OpenMP you build needs to match the version of Clang you compile with. And it isn't easy to tell what that is since Apple changes the version numbers. The R project has a useful page for this: https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/

Comment: Also, annoyingly, this will no longer build on its own, since LLVM 15, because the CMake scripts depend on some other scripts outside this directory. You also have to download `llvmorg-14.0.6/cmake-14.0.6.src.tar.xz`, unzip that, rename it `cmake`, and put it next to the other directory.

Comment: @JensAlfke I'm still using the GitHub runner with macOS 12 and Xcode 14.2 (LLVM 14.0.6), if you happened to solve the issue with Xcode 15.0+ (LLVM 16.0.4), would be great you can submit a Pull Request!